# Consequences of isRouteDisplayed() on map view

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview

I'm just wondering what consequences the method

```
isRouteDisplayed()
```

has, regarding to functionality of a map view...

I have two activities, one displays a route and one doesn't. Is it mandatory to let the first isRouteDisplayed()-Method return true? What effects does it have?

greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> For accounting purposes, the server
>   needs to know whether or not you are
>   currently displaying any kind of route
>   information, such as a set of driving
>   directions. Subclasses must implement
>   this method to truthfully report this
>   information, or be in **violation of our
>   terms of use**.

Comment: hi Macarse, I've already read this, but it seems not to be clear, what is wanted by declaring this...!?

Comment: @poeschlorn: Easy, if you are displaying routes, return true else return false.

Comment: is my english very that bad?^^ I just wanted to know what google affects with this declaration...

Comment: @poeschlorn: You mean what google will do if you don't respect this?
I really don't know, but you would be violating the terms of use.